# Why Angular Change Detection re-renderes component if data didn't change?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-changedetection

Basically for what I understand, Angular Change Detection will re render component if a change happened, or to be precise a property used in the template has changed.
In any other case it will not (unnecessary) re render that component if the value stayed the same.

Here's the example that I've made, button inside the component triggers CD.
Call of that button click event is empty so it doesn't update any value inside the component.
Only this used in the template is a getter function that always returns the same simple value.

So if CD compared previous and current value there is no change so why would is seem that component re rendered since the console log inside the getter function was called.

Or it has crossed my mind, the console.log inside the getter was called during CD value comparison and the component did not really re-render.

Here's the example
https://angular-playground.stackblitz.io.

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core/src/change_detection/constants';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {

  get lastName() {
    console.log('CD triggered rerender')
    return 'Boodin';
  }

  buttonClick(){
    //does nothing, doesnt set any value!
  }
}
```

```
<p>{{lastName}}</p>
<button (click)="buttonClick()">Trigger Change Detection</button>
```

Comment: There's two different types of [change detection strategies](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy). Change your component's to OnPush and see what happens. Also, if you're going to post a stackblitz link on SO, you should be posting the code.

Comment: Secondly, it's all [right here](https://angular.io/guide/zone)

Comment: I've updated my post. Actually strategy is not important in this case since button click event will trigger CD either way. What I would like to know if the console.log in the getter was shown due to CD comparing old and current value of the getter or because component re-rendered.
My understanding is that in this case component should not re-render if the values used in the template didn't change.

Comment: If you'e using a getter, the only way angular can know if it changed was by comparing the values returned from it (i.e. calling the getter). In general, angular runs change detection on every interaction with the DOM. Here's the link to the subsection of the page I originally linked to https://angular.io/guide/zone#when-apps-update-html